# JavaScript: Replacing HTML Element with JS/HTML Tabs

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to set up a test and am having trouble replacing an element with another. I am doing this through an enterprise CRO testing platform.

The page that the test is being built on: https://medcline.com/products/shoulder-relief-pillow

On the right of the image carousel, you'll see a table. This table exists within a div with the class "description".

I am trying to replace that table, using the class "description," with tabbed content but I cannot get it to work. My code:

```
<script type="text/JavaScript">
  var myAnchor = document.getElementsByClassName("description");
  var mySpan = document.createElement("div");
  mySpan.innerHTML = "<div class="tab">
  <button class="tablinks" onclick="openPerk(event, 'Relief')" id="defaultOpen">Relief</button>
  <button class="tablinks" onclick="openPerk(event, 'Features')">Features</button>
</div>

<div id="Relief" class="tabcontent">
  <p><strong>Wake up refreshed!</strong> This patented, three-component Sleep System naturally relieves nighttime shoulder pain so you can sleep better at night and feel better during the day.</p>
<p>Do you experience nighttime acid reflux? For patients with both shoulder pain and nighttime acid reflux, we recommend the <strong><a href="https://medcline.com/products/medcline-reflux-relief-system">MedCline Reflux Relief System</a></strong>.</p>
</div>

<div id="Features" class="tabcontent">
  <ul><li>Patented arm pocket for pain free sleep</li>
  <li>FSA/HSA approved</li>
  <li>95% of usuers report better sleep</li>
  <li>Left- or right-side use</li></ul>
</div>";
  myAnchor.parentNode.replaceChild(mySpan, myAnchor);

  function openPerk(evt, perkName) {
  var i, tabcontent, tablinks;
  tabcontent = document.getElementsByClassName("tabcontent");
  for (i = 0; i < tabcontent.length; i++) {
    tabcontent[i].style.display = "none";
  }
  tablinks = document.getElementsByClassName("tablinks");
  for (i = 0; i < tablinks.length; i++) {
    tablinks[i].className = tablinks[i].className.replace(" active", "");
  }
  document.getElementById(perkName).style.display = "block";
  evt.currentTarget.className += " active";
  }
  document.getElementById("defaultOpen").click();
</script>
```

Thank you for any and all help.

Comment: Are you having any JS errors? This line seems off to me: `mySpan.innerHTML = "<div class="tab">` Maybe wrap `'tab'` on single quotes.

Comment: Using `.innerHTML` with massive amounts of static markup is ill advised. In fact using `.innerHTML` at all is really something to be avoided due to performance and security concerns. Instead, consider just adding that HTML to the page in the first place. Also, don't use [`getElementsByClassName()`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54952088/how-to-modify-style-to-html-elements-styled-externally-with-css-using-js/54952474#54952474), use `.querySelectorAll()` instead.

Comment: Thanks, Scott. That's probably easier -- figuring this out due to limited dev support and to A/B test.

Answer (score 0):

### 1. Escaped Line Breaks/Template Literals

The first change which is most apparent is to modify the `mySpan.innerHTML` section: the HTML string does not work as is because single- and double-quotes do not support unescaped line breaks. You can **escape line breaks** or **use template literals** to resolve this.

#### A. Escaped Line Breaks

Changing all of the unescaped line breaks to `\n` will resolve the issue. It may not be as readable, but there's nothing wrong with this approach.

```js
mySpan.innerHTML = "<div class=\"tab\">\n  <button class=\"tablinks\" onclick=\"openPerk(event, 'Relief')\" id=\"defaultOpen\">Relief</button>\n<!-- ... -->\n</div>";
```

*Note: escaping double quotes is also needed in the string so that it will not result in a syntax error.*

#### B. Template Literals

Using [template literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals#multi-line_strings), any line breaks between the backticks are interpreted the same way as the escaped line breaks.

```js
mySpan.innerHTML = `<div class="tab">
  <button class="tablinks" onclick="openPerk(event, 'Relief')" id="defaultOpen">Relief</button>
<!-- ... -->
</div>`;
```

---

### 2. HTMLCollection, not Element

Another slight error is that the `myAnchor` variable is an [`HTMLCollection`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLCollection) ([`getElementsByClassName`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByClassName) returns an `HTMLCollection` even if there is only one result), so it will not have a `parentNode` property.

Changing the assignment expression to reference the first element in the `HTMLCollection` resolves this:

```js
var myAnchor = document.getElementsByClassName("description")[0];
```

---

### Full Solution

The following code snippet borrows elements necessary from the webpage referenced to show a working example of the changes listed above.

```js
const myAnchor = document.getElementsByClassName("description")[0];
const mySpan = document.createElement("div");
mySpan.innerHTML = `<div class="tab">
      <button class="tablinks" onclick="openPerk(event, 'Relief')" id="defaultOpen">Relief</button>
      <button class="tablinks" onclick="openPerk(event, 'Features')">Features</button>
    </div>
  
    <div id="Relief" class="tabcontent">
      <p><strong>Wake up refreshed!</strong> This patented, three-component Sleep System naturally relieves
      nighttime shoulder pain so you can sleep better at night and feel better during the day.</p>
      <p>Do you experience nighttime acid reflux? For patients with both shoulder pain and nighttime acid reflux, we recommend the
      <strong><a href="https://medcline.com/products/medcline-reflux-relief-system">MedCline Reflux Relief System</a></strong>.</p>
    </div>
  
    <div id="Features" class="tabcontent">
      <ul>
        <li>Patented arm pocket for pain free sleep</li>
        <li>FSA/HSA approved</li>
        <li>95% of usuers report better sleep</li>
        <li>Left- or right-side use</li>
      </ul>
    </div>`;
myAnchor.parentNode.replaceChild(mySpan, myAnchor);

function openPerk(evt, perkName) {
  let i;
  const tabcontent = document.getElementsByClassName("tabcontent");
  for (i = 0; i < tabcontent.length; i++) {
    tabcontent[i].style.display = "none";
  }
  const tablinks = document.getElementsByClassName("tablinks");
  for (i = 0; i < tablinks.length; i++) {
    tablinks[i].className = tablinks[i].className.replace(" active", "");
  }
  document.getElementById(perkName).style.display = "block";
  evt.currentTarget.className += " active";
}
window.openPerk = openPerk;
document.getElementById("defaultOpen").click();
```

```html
<div class="seven columns medium-down--one-whole omega">
  <div class="sale_banner_product">Sale</div>
  <h1 class="product_name">MedCline Shoulder Relief System</h1>
  <div data-oke-reviews-product-listing-rating="">
    <div data-oke-reviews-version="2.13.0" class="okeReviews okeReviews--theme">
      <div class="okeReviews-reviewsSummary js-okeReviews-reviewsSummary is-okeReviews-clickable" data-oke-ga-click-action="Star Rating Summary Click" data-oke-ga-click-label="MedCline Shoulder Relief System" tabindex="0" role="button">
        <div class="okeReviews-reviewsSummary-starRating">
          <span class="okeReviews-starRating okeReviews-starRating--small">
            <span class="okeReviews-a11yText">Rated 4.2 out of 5</span>
          <span class="okeReviews-starRating-indicator" role="presentation">
              <span class="okeReviews-starRating-indicator-layer"></span>
          <span class="okeReviews-starRating-indicator-layer okeReviews-starRating-indicator-layer--foreground" style="width: 85%"></span>
          </span>
          </span>
        </div>
        <div class="okeReviews-reviewsSummary-ratingCount">
          <span aria-hidden="true">364 Reviews</span>
          <span class="okeReviews-a11yText">Based on 364 reviews</span>
        </div>
        <span class="okeReviews-a11yText">Click to go to reviews</span>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="feature_divider"></div>
  <div class="modal_price">
    <div class="price__container price__container--display-price-false "> <span content="199.99" class="sale"> <span class="current_price"> <span class="money">$199.99</span></span>
      </span> <span class="was_price"> $249.99</span> <span class="sale savings"> You Save 20% (<span class="money">$50.00</span>)</span>
    </div>
    <div class="sold-out__container"> <span class="sold_out"></span></div>
  </div>
  <div class="description">
    <div class="desktop-only">
      <b></b>
      <table class="compare_table" id="lp_blue" style="width: 100%;">
        <tbody>
          <tr>
            <th></th>
            <th>MedCline</th>
            <th>The Other Guys</th>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Patented Arm Pocket for Pain Free Sleep</td>
            <td>✓</td>
            <td>✕</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>FSA/HSA Approved</td>
            <td>✓</td>
            <td>✕</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>95% of Users Report Better Sleep</td>
            <td>✓</td>
            <td>✕</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Left or Right-Side Use</td>
            <td>✓</td>
            <td>✕</td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </div>
    <dl class="faqAccordion right-for-you mobile-only">
      <dt><button type="button" aria-expanded="false">How MedCline compares to the competition</button></dt>
      <dd id="panel-05" aria-hidden="true">
        <table style="width: 100%;" id="lp_blue" class="compare_table">
          <tbody>
            <tr>
              <th></th>
              <th>MedCline</th>
              <th>The Other Guys</th>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>Patented Arm Pocket for Pain Free Sleep</td>
              <td>✓</td>
              <td>✕</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>FSA/HSA Approved</td>
              <td>✓</td>
              <td>✕</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>95% of Users Report Better Sleep</td>
              <td>✓</td>
              <td>✕</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>Left or Right-Side Use</td>
              <td>✓</td>
              <td>✕</td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </dd>
    </dl>
  </div>
  <div class="clearfix product_form init smart-payment-button--false  product_form--dropdown" id="product-form-4791002857607" data-product-form="" data-options-size="1" data-money-format="${{amount}}" data-shop-currency="USD" data-select-id="product-select-4791002857607"
    data-enable-state="true" data-product="" data-product-id="4791002857607">
    <form method="post" action="/cart/add" id="product_form_4791002857607" accept-charset="UTF-8" class="shopify-product-form" enctype="multipart/form-data"><input type="hidden" name="form_type" value="product"><input type="hidden" name="utf8" value="✓"> <input type="hidden" name="id" value="33912967626887">
      <div class="purchase-details">
        <div class="purchase-details__quantity product-quantity-box"> <label for="quantity">Qty</label> <span class="ss-icon product-minus js-change-quantity" data-func="minus"><span class="icon-minus"></span></span> <input type="number" min="1" size="2" class="quantity" name="quantity" id="quantity" value="1">          <span class="ss-icon product-plus js-change-quantity" data-func="plus"><span class="icon-plus"></span></span>
        </div>
        <div class="purchase-details__buttons purchase-details__spb--false ">
          <a class="bundleupgrade__trigger quick-pay-off" js-trigger-bundle="">ADD TO CART</a> <button type="button" name="add" class=" ajax-submit action_button add_to_cart  " data-label="Add to Cart"> <span class="text"> Add to Cart</span> <svg x="0px" y="0px" width="32px" height="32px" viewBox="0 0 32 32" class="checkmark">
              <path fill="none" stroke-width="2" stroke-linecap="square" stroke-miterlimit="10" d="M9,17l3.9,3.9c0.1,0.1,0.2,0.1,0.3,0L23,11"></path>
            </svg></button>
        </div>
        <shopify-payment-terms variant-id="33912967626887" shopify-meta="{&quot;variants&quot;:[{&quot;id&quot;:33912967626887,&quot;price&quot;:&quot;$49.99&quot;,&quot;eligible&quot;:true}],&quot;min_price&quot;:&quot;$50&quot;,&quot;max_price&quot;:&quot;$3000&quot;}"></shopify-payment-terms>
        <div class="cf-order-by-outer" style="display:none;"> Order NOW and get it by:&nbsp;<span class="cf-order-by-date"></span></div>
      </div>
    </form>
  </div>
</div>
```